# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $V B V^{-1}$, show that it is also an eigenvalue for $B$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A,B$ is a $m \times m$ matrix such that $A=V B V^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $V$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, show that it is also an eigenvalue for $B$.

My answer: I tried to solve it by taking the $\det$ and I was correct but my teacher dose not want that! He said, *"if $Ax=\lambda x$, show that $By=\lambda y$"*. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: $y = V^{-1}x$.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the basic **definition** of "eigenvalue".  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for A then there exist a vector, v, such that $Av= \lambda v$. Since $A= VBV^{-1}$, then $Av= VBV^{-1}v$ and $V^{-1}Av= BV^{-1}v$.  But $Av= \lambda v$ so $V^{-1}Av= V^{-1}(\lambda v)= \lambda V^{-1}v$ so $\lambda V^{-1}v= B(V^{-1}v)$.  Taking $u= V^{-1}v$, we have $Bu= \lambda u$.

Comment: Oh, I see ... thank you ^^